# Yii2: how to order activeRecord relation query by related field?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-model

I want to execute this query:

```
$topics = ForumTopic::find()
            ->with([                
                'lastPost' => function($query) {
                    $query->select(['id', 'ctime']);
                },
            ])
            ->orderBy('lastPost.ctime DESC')
            ->all();
```

Relation declared in ForumTopic like this:

```
public function getLastPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ForumPost::className(), ['id' => 'lastPostId']);
}
```

But my query fails (because yii2 make all queries separate and don't join tables).
Is any way to achive my purpose by yii2 activeRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just for clarification, the right answer is:

```
$topics = ForumTopic::find()
            ->alias('t')
            ->select(['t.*','l.ctime lastPostCtime'])
            ->joinWith([
                'lastPost l' => function($query) {
                    $query->select(['l.id', 'l.ctime', 'l.userId', 'l.guestName']);
                },
            ])
            ->orderBy('lastPostCtime DESC')
            ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$topics = ForumTopic::find()
        ->with([                
            'lastPost' => function($query) {
                $query->select(['id', 'ctime']);
            },
        ])
        ->orderBy([ForumPost::tableName() . '.ctime' => SORT_DESC])
        ->all();
```

Comment: `lastPostId` is the field of **ForumTopic** model (not ForumPost). This is actually mentioned in relation declaration (this is described in the Guide: `An easy rule to remember this is, as you see in the example above, you write the column that belongs to the related Active Record directly next to it.`).

Comment: So how it helps to retrieve `lastPostId` in lastPost relation select?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was too hasty, I've updated it, try now.

Comment: This is also didn't worked out. Exception tells `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'forum_post.ctime' in 'order clause' The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM forum_topic ORDER BY forum_post.ctime` As I mentioned in my question the main problem is that yii2 activeRecord don't join tables in eager loading (it makes separate queries). (In yii1 it did it.)

Comment: Try `joinWith` instead `with`.